# Found .net core version different by typing `dotnet` and `dotnet --version` in OSX

Tags: .net, macos, version

Anyone knows why when I type `dotnet --version` get 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177, but get 1.1.0 when type `dotnet`?

```
Ian-MBP:C# Ian_Weng$ dotnet --version
1.0.0-preview2-1-003177
Ian-MBP:C# Ian_Weng$ dotnet

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like when you run `dotnet`, the "version" you are seeing is the version of something called the "Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host", whereas when you run `dotnet --version` or `dotnet --info`, the "version" you are seeing is the version of something called the "Microsoft .NET Core SDK".

There is [a GitHub issue in the .NET Core CLI repository](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3773) discussing the less than ideal information architecture at play here. You can read through the issue to get some insight and/or add your own comments to let the developers know what you think.